# node-poppler convert pdf to jpeg with adobe pi std checkboxes

Tags: adobe-indesign, poppler

I'm using node-poppler 23.05.0-r0 to convert pdfs to jpeg  and came across an issue with pdf's created with Adobe InDesign 18.1 that build checkboxes with adobe pi std. When they are converted to jpegs it removes the checkmark and displays blank.

I've attempted to install several different fonts to see if that helps but no luck yet. One of the unique things about these forms is when I inspect document properties I don't see a reference to adobepistd as a font but I'm not sure if I should see it there? I'm going to keep tinkering but I feel like others may of ran into this as well.

Docker fonts installed: (manually attempted to install AdobePiStd.otf file but still no checkmark)

```
RUN apk add --no-cache "poppler>${POPPLER_VERSION}" "poppler-utils>${POPPLER_VERSION}" "poppler-glib>${POPPLER_VERSION}" \
            --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/ \
            --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/
RUN apk add --no-cache  pdfgrep fontconfig freetype ttf-liberation
RUN fc-cache -f

RUN apk --update add font-freefont fontconfig msttcorefonts-installer ghostscript-fonts && \
update-ms-fonts && \
fc-cache -f -v

WORKDIR '/tmp'
COPY AdobePiStd.otf /tmp/AdobePiStd.otf
RUN cp -r /tmp/AdobePiStd.otf /usr/share/fonts/freefont/AdobePiStd.otf
RUN fc-cache -f -v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the forms we were having issues with only came from Adobe InDesign 18.1. This version of InDesign has documented issues with embedding fonts:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/update-from-18-0-to-18-1-removed-the-ability-to-embed-fonts-in-a-pdf/m-p/13732117/highlight/true

We had the author of the forms update to InDesign 18.5 (Latest) and recreate the forms. The fonts needed were embedded in the document properties and everything worked as expected.

If the pdfs document properties application is, "Adobe InDesign 18.1" and your checkboxes are disappearing you need to go back to the pdf author and have them update there form with latest Adobe InDesign software or any version not 18.1.